# Submit AMP form on wordpress page (http)

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

We're making a landing page using Google's AMP: https://developers.google.com/adwords/amp/landing-pages

Usually we submit to admin-post and do our ajax form logic inside functions.php.

```
<form" target="_top" action-xhr="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>"  method="post">
</form>
```

Our website uses http rather than https and AMP doesn't allow this value for action. Is there a way I can put my php form logic on the same page and make the form submit to that?

Comment: AMP form submit must have a https url to submit to https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form just upgrade to https (and enjoy the benefits of http/2 & TLS)

Comment: not helpful at all

Comment: instead of using `http:`, `https:` use `//`. it will work with amp form